# What’s the proper way to wire this light switch?

Tags: light

I’m thinking the two red wires go to the switch wires and the blue wire with the white neutral?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### One black to red, the other black to blue, white to white, green to a ground screw in the back of the box.

This is relatively easy, as your wiring is in conduit and your switch does not care about line vs load either.  Simply connect one of the switch's black wires to the red wire, the other black wire on the switch to the blue wire, cut the white wire and nut both ends to the  white neutral pigtail, and the switch's green grounding pigtail to a 10-32 grounding screw driven into the matching hole on the back of the box in thew all.

Comment: I’m guessing I’ll have to cut the white wire in the back and connect the two ends with the neutral on the switch since that wire continues into the wall? Or should I disregard that wire?

Comment: @Gusbus001 yeah, I didn't see that was a loop of wire

Comment: How much would that complicate things?

Comment: @Gusbus001 not much at all!

Comment: Just bypass the neutral and connect the red/blue to switch?

Comment: @Gusbus001 -- the switch needs neutral, so you'll have to cut into the loop and splice the switch's neutral in with the two cut ends